# How do I find the account having the maximum balance in each branch of a bank using SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I find the account having the maximum balance in each branch of a bank using SQL? I have a table having 3 columns account number, balance and branch.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Group by branch and max(balance) your data.

Comment: @Maxim: Then you get the maximum balance for each branch. The corresponding account is still missing.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @RobertKock absolutely right. I forgot about account

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server the following will work using ROW_NUMBER():

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_A
(
BALANCE INT,
BRANCH VARCHAR(20),
ACCOUNT INT
)


INSERT INTO #TEMP_A
VALUES(100,'WEST',001)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_A
VALUES(200,'WEST',002)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_A
VALUES(400,'EAST',003)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_A
VALUES(500,'EAST',004)

SELECT ACCOUNT FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BRANCH ORDER BY BALANCE DESC) AS ROWNUM,* FROM #TEMP_A
) AS X WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    SELECT DISTINCT(A.ACCOUNT), TMP.BRANCH, TMP.AMT
    FROM   TABLE  A,
 (  SELECT              BRANCH, MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMT
    FROM   TABLE
    GROUP BY              BRANCH) AS TMP
    WHERE A.BRANCH = TMP.BRANCH
    AND   A.AMOUNT = TMP.AMT
    GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT, TMP.BRANCH, TMP.AMT ;
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+